# Jquery slideDown on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to have a slide(down) toggle but would like the panel to line up neatly along the left edge of the button. I don't want to hard code margin, position, px, etc but want the slide down panel to always be "in relation" to (and relative) the (left bottom of) button.

What am I missing?

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .slideToggleBox{
        float:left;
        padding:8px;
        margin:16px;
        border:1px solid red;
        width:200px;
        height:50px;
        background-color:blue;
        color:white;
        position:fixed;
        left:-10.5px;
        top:2.3%;
    }
    .clear{
        clear:both;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="clear">
     <button id=slideToggle>slideToggle()</button>
    <br/>
    <div class="slideToggleBox">
        slideToggle()
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#slideToggle").click(function () {
   $('.slideToggleBox').slideToggle();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TTFhU/

Comment: Is http://jsfiddle.net/TTFhU/4/ good enough? If not, could you clarify your requirements a bit?

Comment: I wanted it to appear to come almost out of the bottom button itself. Should I be using the .offset method to get the coordinates of button first? Also should I be using relative values?

Comment: If you want it to overlap the button, I'd just specify a negative `margin-top` - http://jsfiddle.net/TTFhU/5/. I try and avoid using `position: relative` until it actually becomes necessary.

Comment: `position: relative` should be fine too though: http://jsfiddle.net/TTFhU/6/

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Added a [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/NWNNk/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class=slideToggle>slideToggle()</button>
  <div class="slideToggleBox">slideToggle()</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class=slideToggle>slideToggle()</button>
  <div class="slideToggleBox">slideToggle()</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
  float:left;
  width:200px;
}
.slideToggleBox {
  float:left;
  border:1px solid red;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-left:1px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".slideToggle").click(function () {
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Hi Wolf - I wanted it to appear to come almost out of the bottom button itself. Should I be using the .offset method to get the coordinates of button first? Also should I be using relative values? –

Comment: Updated the code according to this. Is this, what you want to achieve?